# How do games like Minecraft generate entire worlds from a seed number?

Tags: procedural-generation

I want to generate a completely unique world with biomes (like what Minecraft and similar games do). I don't understand how they generate these entire worlds from a single "seed" number. Can someone provide a basic overview of the technique?

Comment: Notch actually wrote [a blog post about terrain generation](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361), which is now completely obsolete since the new code's got biomes and FRACTALS and other such wizardry. There never was a part 2, either.

Answer (score 31):

1. **How do you generate random X from a seed?**  a seed value is the initial state of a random number generator. In most programming languages, you can set this seed. For example, C uses `srand()`. If you don't specify a specific seed to start with, usually a timestamp value is used as the seed. That way, each time you run, the random numbers are different.

   ```
   // C example
   srand(1);
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
       printf("%d\n", rand());
   srand(1);
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
       printf("%d\n", rand());

   1270216262 
   1085377743 
   1481765933
   1270216262 
   1085377743 
   1481765933
   ```

   As you can see, whenever you seed with a certain value (I used 1 as a seed), the resulting random numbers are the same.
2. **How do you create a minecraft-life world based on random numbers?**  [Notch has a post about this.](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1)  Also, you can check out other people's tutorials on "minecraft-like worlds". I enjoyed this one, for example: [Minecraft-like rendering in OpenGL 4](http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/dec/09/minecraft-like-rendering-experiments-in-opengl-4/). The basic idea is to use Perlin noise (or simplex noise). Here is a good question about noise functions: [Understanding Perlin Noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18330/understanding-perlin-noise)

Comment: Actually, you wont be able to use Perlin Noise I'm afraid minecraft has over-hanging cliffs, caves and so on, and PN cannot into that.

Comment: Perlin noise is just a noise system which you can use as part of a larger terrain generation method. eg. You can use 3D perlin noise with an altitude-dependent threshold value to generate cliffs, caves, etc. (Edit - in fact, I see from the link in the answer that is exactly what Notch was doing at one point.)

Comment: +1 Kylotan. Here's the quote from Notch's blog: "Specifically, there’s no way for [2D Perlin heightmap] to generate any overhangs.

So I switched the system over into a similar system based off 3D Perlin noise. Instead of sampling the “ground height”, I treated the noise value as the “density”, where anything lower than 0 would be air, and anything higher than or equal to 0 would be ground. "