# How to create a seamless 5D noise function?

Tags: noise

I would like to create a seamless 3D Texture, I have read that it's doable with a 5D noise function but I can't find any implementation and the math is over my head here.

How can I create a 5D noise function to create a seamless 3D texture?

Comment: What do you mean by 3d texture?

Comment: I mean a texture which contains multiple tiles, 64x64 pixels per tile and 8x8 rows / columns so each tile can be mapped to a slice of a cube.

Comment: OK, I figured, I just wanted to make sure.  I have done this with 4D noise, but I have never done this with 5D noise.  This is an interesting question.  The generation of this data will more than likely take a while.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if its 4D noise, I searched and only found that it's doable with 5D noise, it just has to be seamless.

Comment: Yeah, the 4D noise implementation is to create a seamless 2D texture.  I think you might actually have to use 6D noise to make seamless 3D like you are trying to do.  I personally cannot visualize how to do this at all.

Here is the 2D implementation, it might help you...   http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-2/#wrap2

Comment: Have you considered, how long a 5 dimensional noise would generate?

Comment: Does this help? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23625/41628

Comment: @Ferrybig yes, that’s the proper way to do it (but one should use John Calsbeek’s answer rather than the accepted one)