# How do I create tileable 3D Perlin/Simplex noise?

Tags: tiles, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

I have a library which provides functions for 1/2/3/4-D simplex noise. With that I successfuly created a tileable 2D cloud texture (see [How do you generate tileable Perlin noise?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise)).
Now I want to create a tileable 3D cloud volume. It only has to be tileable in 2 dimension of course.

How can I achieve this? Do I need higher dimension than 4D noise?