# Need to generate seamless gradient noise texture for water Shader

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, noise

I need to generate something like this

[image]

for my water Shader, because on fly calculations are to expensive for mobile (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Gradient-Noise-Node.html). The texture needs to be seamless. I currently clueless where and how to make this happen (especially about the seamless thing). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Presumably you [searched through past Q&A on making tiling Perlin or Simplex Noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=tiling+perlin)? What have you tried based on your research so far?

Comment: Reading trough this https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise . I do not quite understand if gradient noise is same as Perlin.

Comment: Gradient noise is a general category of noise generation strategies. Perlin Noise and Simplex Noise are two popular and related algorithms that use this gradient-based strategy. Perlin is arguably a bit easier to tile in a rectangular domain, since simplex noise uses an equilateral triangular grid whose period parallelogram doesn't exactly match a power-of-two texture size.

Comment: Can do, or you can simply delete the question yourself if you're satisfied with answers you've found elsewhere.