# Rotating UVs by X degrees

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I would like to make a tileable texture with UV noise in Unity Shader Graph **only**, but I have a problem.

After creating simple noise from UV, I want to rotate it by 90 degrees, but the node `Rotate` (as well as `Rotate About Axis`) doesn't rotate my UV (like a picture in PS), instead it changes the colors in it from black & white to red (yellow, green, ...) & black.

Could you tell me please, how to fix it?
[image: rotated result]

Some context :

Based on the answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23631 , I want to rotate the noise three times (so 0° + 90° + 180° + 270°), multiply them and thus normalize the edges to make the texture tileable.

Instead of it, even at 0° rotation the color of noise is changed to yellow somehow and the multiplication is everything but not the result I want.
That's how I wanted to do it:
[image: idea]

Comment: Did you mean to put the rotate node between the UV source and the noise node? It's *the domain* of the noise you want to rotate (its input), not the output intensities.

Comment: @DMGregory i guess yes (?), but would it be more effective to multiply the noise itself than to multiply the UVs?

Comment: One gets you the result you want, the other does not. So I think that makes the choice clear.