# Island Generation Library

Tags: java, maps, procedural-generation, open-source, heightmap

Can anyone recommend a tile map generator (written in Java is a plus), where one can control some land types? For example: islands, large continents, singe large continent, archipelago, etc.

I've been reading through many posts on the subject, it almost seems like many are just rolling their own. Before creating my own, I'm wondering if there's already an open source implementation that I might not be finding.

If not, it seems like using Perlin Noise is a popular choice.

Some articles I've been reading:

http://simblob.blogspot.com/2010/01/simple-map-generation.html

[Generate islands/continents with simplex noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/generate-islands-continents-with-simplex-noise)

https://sites.google.com/site/minecraftlandgenerator/

Comment: If you do roll your own, you might find [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) useful.

Comment: Hmm yes interesting read - I'll have to go through a few times to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Notch made the source for Minicraft open for everyone. it uses a Diamond Square algorithm that i nicked for a C# version (almost a copy paste) maybe worth checking that out.

I have never used java before and i was up and running with it within minutes

Comment: Interesting, but are you using this for a tile based world (continent sized?). My game is similar to the scale of Civilization, where an entire world is represented in something like a 100x50 tilemap. Notch's game appears to look like the camera is 10 meters off the ground (best way I can describe it). Thanks

Comment: If my understanding of your problem is correct that doesn't matter all you are looking to achieve is a 2d array of tile the camera position has no relevance to the world map